# Renamed a file uploaded via Angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, file-upload

**In a nutshell, I need to rename files uploaded via Angular and Node and make that new name available to both the back and front ends (I think). What is the best practice for doing so?**

I am using a file upload plugin (https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) in an Angularjs app. The upload hits a route handled by Nodejs, uploads the file then, on success, angular saves the file name into a users account. However, if two people upload a file of the same name there will be a conflict so I need to rename each file (perhaps by adding a date and time).

My code works as follows:

1. Angular handles the upload, hitting a route that node can use.
2. Node move the file into place.
3. on success, angular saves the file name into the user's account.

It appears I cannot rename the file prior to uploading. If I rename the file via node after it has been moved into place I run into the issue of needing to get that new name back to angular for saving into the database. Not sure of the best way to approach this process.

Here is my current file upload code (works fine, just doesn't rename the file):

In Angular...

```
   $scope.onFileSelect = function ($file) {
        var photo = $file[0];
        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: '/upload/userphoto',
            headers: {'Content-Type': photo.type},
            file: photo,
            method: 'POST'
        }).progress(function (evt) {
            //removed for brevity
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            User.currentUser.user_profile_image = photo.name;
            User.updateUser();
        }).error(function (err) { 
            //removed for brevity 
        });
    };
```

The post route, `/upload/userphoto` is matched in node with:

```
exports.uploadProfilePhoto = function(req, res) {
    var callbacks = {};

    callbacks.uploadSuccess = function(){
        res.json('success');
    };

    callbacks.uploadFailure = function(err){
        //removed for brevity
    };

    user.handleUserImageUpload(req.files, callbacks);
};
```

Which sets some callbacks and then hits `handleUserImageUpload()` which is:

```
this.handleUserImageUpload = function(params, callbacks) {
    fs.readFile(params.file.path, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            callbacks.uploadFailure(err);
        }
        var newPath = path.resolve("./public/fileupload/userphotos/" + params.file.filename);
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
            if(err){
                callbacks.uploadFailure(err);
            }
            callbacks.uploadSuccess();
        });
    });
};
```

Which, assuming success, takes us back to the success handler of the first bit of Angular code above.  I know I can rename the file in the `handleUserImageUpload()` method with `fs.rename()` like (just a hard coded example... I would actually take into account the file type and existing name plus add a random string or account identifier):

```
var renamedPath = path.resolve("./public/fileupload/userphotos/" + "abc123.jpg");
fs.rename(newPath, renamedPath);
```

But then I don't have that new name available when I go to save the file info into the user's account. I guess I could pass it back in the success callback? Is that the best way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be what I suspected... pass the value in the callback. So I added the following to `handleUserImageUpload()`...

```
// grab the extension
var fileExtension = '.' + params.file.filename.split('.').pop();

// rename the file with a sufficiently random value and add the file extension back
var renamedFile =  Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + new Date().getTime() + fileExtension;

//set up the new path for use in fs.rename()
var renamedPath = path.resolve("./public/fileupload/userphotos/" + renamedFile);

// Make it so
fs.rename(newPath, renamedPath);

// pass the new name to the callback
callbacks.uploadSuccess(renamedFile);
```

In the function that created the callbacks, `uploadProfilePhoto()`, I needed to make one important change, swap `json` with `send` (otherwise I would get quotation marks added to the value)

```
//res.json('success');
res.send(renamedFile);
```

Then I could access the this name as the `data` value in my Angular success handler.